# Не загружается node.js модуль в main.js файле приложения на electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, модули, electron

Я разрабатываю приложение на electron.js и main.js стал слишком большим, я решил разбить его на модули. Но некоторые модули не грузятся и нарушают загрузку следующих после них модулей
Мне необходимо установить причину такого поведения
Так как нужно передать в модули созданное окно приложения для вызова событий клиента, использую следующую систему загрузки модулей:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...options
  });

  requireModules();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Загрузить модули после создания окна приложения
const requireModules = () => {
  require('./modulesMain/open')(mainWindow);
  require('./modulesMain/watchers')(mainWindow);

  require('./modulesMain/testModule')(mainWindow);
};
```

Модули после `require('./modulesMain/watchers')(mainWindow);` не загружаются
Код модуля `watchers`:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { ipcMain } = electron;
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

const { transfPathForWin } = require('./helpersMain/helpers');

let watchedArray = [];

module.exports = (mainWindow) => {
  ipcMain.on('start-watching-dir', (event, dirPath, tabId) => {
    const perviouslyThisTab = watchedArray.find((item) => item.id === tabId);

    if (perviouslyThisTab) {
      perviouslyThisTab.watcher.close();
    }

    watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => item.id !== tabId);
    try {
        const winDirPath = transfPathForWin(dirPath);

        const watcher = chokidar.watch(winDirPath, {
          persistent: true,
          ignored: '*.sys',
          ignoreInitial: true,
          followSymlinks: true,
          cwd: '.',
          disableGlobbing: false,
          usePolling: false,
          interval: 100,
          binaryInterval: 300,
          alwaysStat: false,
          depth: 0,
          awaitWriteFinish: {
            stabilityThreshold: 2000,
            pollInterval: 100,
          },
          ignorePermissionErrors: false,
          atomic: true,
        });

        // Add event listeners.
        watcher
          .on('add', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been added`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('change', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('unlink', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been removed`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('ready', () =>
            console.log('Initial scan complete. Ready for changes')
          )
          .on('addDir', (path) => {
            if (path === '..\\..\\..') return;
            console.log(`Directory ${path} has been added`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          });
         .on('unlinkDir', (path) => {
           if (path === '..\\..\\..') return;
           console.log(`Directory ${path} has been removed`);
           mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
         });

        watchedArray.push({ id: tabId, path: dirPath, watcher });
    } catch (err) {
      // error watching - no access or something
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on('stop-watching-dir', (event, dirPath, tabId) => {
    const watchedItem = watchedArray.find((item) => item.id === tabId);

    try {
      watchedItem.watcher.close();

      watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => item.id !== tabId);
    } catch (err) {
      // error watching - no access or something
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on('stop-watching-all', (event) => {
    watchedArray.map((item) => item.watcher.close());
    watchedArray = [];
  });

  ipcMain.on('close-tabs', (event, data) => {
    const { excludedTabs } = data;
    watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => {
      if (excludedTabs.includes(item.id)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        item.watcher.close();
        return false;
      }
    });

    console.log('watchedArray', watchedArray);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ошибку: она была из-за некорректного импорта `const { transfPathForWin } = require('./helpersMain/helpers');` вместо `const { transfPathForWin } = require('../helpersMain/helpers');`, что вызвало ошибку конвертации путей. В дополнение, я забыл добавить `console.log(err)` в инструкцию `catch(err)`, так что произошла ошибка `chokidar` без вывода в консоль. Причиной остановки загрузки модулей после `watchers` была система загрузки модулей с помощью функций `module.exports = (mainWindow) => {...code}`. Так если в функции ошибка, то и главная функция для загрузки модулей `requireModules` прекратит своё выполнение и, следовательно, остальные модули не будут загружены